# Link to another page, scrolled to a div anchor

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor, scrolltop

Is it possible to have a link to another page on your site, but have the browser scrolled to an anchor div? For example most of my site's content is on the homepage, divided in sections such as about, contact, etc.

I want to be able to link from another sub page, to one of these divs.

The following code does just this, but only works when the link is on the same page as the destination:

```
<a href="#about" id="about-link">About</a>
```

The JS:

```
$("#about-link").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".wrapper_about").offset().top
  }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten it to work by applying this method:

```
<a href="#about" id="about-link">About</a>
```

The JS:

```
$("#about-link").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top // Target hash not div
  }, 0);
});
```

It's important to note that your href target must match the ID of the element you want to anchor to.

Answer (score 1):

Your link has to include the other page's filename (and filepath, if it's not in the same directory):

```
<a href="other_page.html#about" id="about-link">About</a>
```

Comment: Before applying your change, the link destination would equal "example.com/subpage/#about" instead of example.com/#about. With your change the url destination is correct and it takes me to the homepage, but with no scrolling to the anchor.

Comment: I should note it's a wordpress installation, so I applied "index.php#about"

Comment: It depends what your anchor ID is: In your example HTML you have `#about`, but in your jQuery you have `.wrapper_about` (?)

Comment: Well #about-link is the link ID that triggers the on click jQuery, .about_wrapper is the scroll top offset destination and href I set to #about, but it was my understanding that's just amended to the URL for looks sake, if I change the ahref to something like #test, the code still works in the working scenario where the link is not on another page.

Comment: You're right that the anchor element's ID must match the href for this to work when linking to a different page, I also had to change the scroll top offset to target $(window.location.hash) instead of the anchor div. Thanks for the help!